# what is the reason of not reading the property of props variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*update: i removed this from this.props. but now nothing is showing in the localhost.*

i am trying to write a blog page in react. Here is my blog.js:

```
import React from 'react'
const Blog=props=>{
    const {title,author,content}=this.props
    return(
        <div>
         <h2>{title}</h2>
              <h5><i>{author}</i></h5>
              <br/>
              <h3>{content}</h3>
                  </div>
    )
}

export default Blog
```

and my App.js is below:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Blog from './Blog'
class App extends Component {
    render(){
        const posts=[
            {
                title:'First',
                author:'Anonymous',
                content:'first Post',
            },
            {
                title:'Second',
                author:'Anonymous',
                content:'Second Post',
            },
            {
                title:'third',
                author:'Anonymous',
                content:'Second Post',
            },
        ]
            return (  
                <div className="container">
                    <Blog postData={posts}/>
                </div>
            );
        }

    }

export default App ;
```

while i excute npm start there is no error but in the broswer it is saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
Blog
C:/Myfiles/python/Django/djangorest/booklearn/test-cases/src/Blog.js:5
  2 | 
  3 | 
  4 | const Blog=props=>{
> 5 |     const {title,author,content}=this.props
  6 |     return(
  7 |         
  8 |         <div>
```

i am running out of options. How can i solve this thing?

i have started reactjs very recent. any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Replace this.props with props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a functional component and passing in `props` as an argument to your function (`props =>`). You do not need to use `this.props` just `props` will work.

You are passing in an array of posts under the prop name 'postData'. In your blog component you need to:

```
import React from 'react'
const Blog=props=>{

return props.postData.map((post) => {
const { title, author, content } = post;
return (
  <div key={title}>
         <h2>{title}</h2>
              <h5><i>{author}</i></h5>
              <br/>
              <h3>{content}</h3>
                  </div>
    );
});
}

export default Blog;
```

Comment: well, the error has gone but http://localhost:3000/ page is blank after executing npm start. nothing is showing. i am just clueless now

Comment: updated my answer, but really your should just have created a new question i think

Comment: it worked....i had no idea to use map here....in javascript i used...but i never throught.... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove `this` since its not a class and props are being passed as the first parameter of the function.

```
import React from 'react'
const Blog = (props) => {
    const { title,author,content } = props;
    return(
        <div>
         <h2>{title}</h2>
              <h5><i>{author}</i></h5>
              <br/>
              <h3>{content}</h3>
                  </div>
    )
}

export default Blog
```

Comment: i did it. the error has gone but localhost:3000 page is blank after executing npm start. nothing is showing.

Comment: I believe you still need to use `react-dom` to render your component.
See: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#step-3-create-a-react-component